# Different background images in Conemu tabs

Tags: conemu

Is it possible to assign different background images to tabs in Conemu?

Console2 supports custom backgrounds per tab, and I'd like something similar to the functionality it provides.

Perhaps I can set this in *Startup -> Tasks* or via the command line of a running tab, but I can't find any information on it.

e.g.

```
Tab1 cmd "cmd.png"
Tab2 powershell "ps.png"
Tab3 Visual Studio Command Prompt "vs.png"
Tab4 Admin:cmd "warning.png"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per-tab backgrounds are not supported in the current version.

Comment: any plans on supporting this? I've used Console2 for what seems ages, and adapting to ConEmu is pretty hard since it has no all-in-your-face visual cues to indicate I'm in a different tab..

Comment: In plans, yes. As for now - you may use different color schemes via App distinct.